# How do I change Data into percentages

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm very green in using R and programming in general. I want to know how to change numbers from an imported CSV file into percentages and round them into the nearest hundredths. Thanks

Comment: You need to clarify a percentage of what?  A percentage involves two values.  We often calculate a percentage increase of a point relative to average or minimum value, for example.

Comment: Are you are wanting to change fractions (e.g., 0.15678543) to rounded percentages?  Consider putting sample data and desired output into your question.